# TypeLite generate external modules?

Tags: typelite

I am trying to generate external modules rather than a type definition file.  I believe I need to do the following:

1. Change the extension of the file to .ts instead of .d.ts.
2. Generate one file per module.
3. Add the key word "Export" in front of each interface and enum.

I was easily able to change the extension of the file by changing the "output extension" setting in the tt file.

I cannot figure out how to split the modules into separate files.

I cannot figure out how to add the Export key word to each interface.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

TypeLITE doesn't support generating multiple files. This feature has been requested by several users, but I am not aware of a simple way to generate multiple files from the single tt file.

`export` keyword can't be added without changing source code of the library (`TsGenerator.cs`). This is very specific requirement, so I probably won't add it to the library.

Comment: I added the functionality I needed for my own use and have made a [pull request](https://bitbucket.org/LukasKabrt/typelite/pull-request/9/support-for-file-per-module).

Comment: I've tried to use ToModules and I could definitely use some examples/documentation.

Answer (score 0):

TypeLite is a good project but lacking in Documentation and examples, it's open source so anyone can contribute and make it better.

As for creating a file per class i solved it using the code below.

```
    private static void GenerateTypeScriptContracts(string assemblyFile, string outputPath)
    {
        // Clean TS Folder
        System.IO.DirectoryInfo di = new DirectoryInfo(outputPath);

        foreach (FileInfo file in di.GetFiles())
        {
            file.Delete();
        }
        // --

        var assembly = Assembly.LoadFrom(assemblyFile);

        // If you want a subset of classes from this assembly, filter them here
        var models = assembly.GetTypes();

        foreach (var model in models)
        {
            var generator = new TypeScriptFluent()
                .WithConvertor<Guid>(c => "string")
                .WithMemberFormatter((identifier) => Char.ToLower(identifier.Name[0]) + identifier.Name.Substring(1));

            generator.ModelBuilder.Add(model);

            // Generate TS interface definitions
            var tsClassDefinitions = generator.Generate(TsGeneratorOutput.Properties | TsGeneratorOutput.Fields);
            File.WriteAllText(Path.Combine(outputPath, "I" + model.FullName.Replace("ProjectName.DtoModels.", "") + ".ts"), tsClassDefinitions);
        }
    }
```